# Andengine Live Wallpaper Galaxy S4 Touch Issues

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper, galaxy

I have a published live wallpaper with Andengine and I received an email from someone saying touch is not working on their device. He did say it IS working while he is previewing the wallpaper, but when it is set to the background touch doesn't work any longer. As far as I know, this is only on S4, as I have tested it on the s3 and many other devices.

Here is my touch code for the wallpaper. This is all inside the OnCreateScene method.

```
mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

Sprite buttonSprite = new Sprite(279, 618, btnTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
                 @Override
                   public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                       if(pTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                           randomSpawn();
                       }
                return true;
        }
        };
mScene.registerTouchArea(buttonSprite);
mScene.attachChild(buttonSprite);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are similar issues with the S3. Samsung overrode teh default behavior of LiveWallpapers. They do not scroll, and do not receive touch events as they should. Boo, Samsung. This is the "touch wiz" skin.

Comment: Hmm, that is sad. Do you think for now I should then remove the S4 from devices it can be installed on?

Comment: Does it depend on touch? or is there still some value? You should definitely call out the issue though.

Comment: It doesn't depend 100% on touch, but I have a button that does something.